# Auto Optimizer Stats Collection Job Causing Oracle RDS Database to Restart

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, oracle19c

We have a Oracle 19C database (19.0.0.0.ru-2021-04.rur-2021-04.r1) on AWS RDS which is hosted on an 4 CPU 32 GB RAM instance. The size of the database is not big (35 GB) and the PGA Aggregate Limit is 8GB & Target is 4GB. Whenever the scheduled internal Oracle Auto Optimizer Stats Collection Job (ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_nnn) runs then it consumes substantially high PGA memory (approx 7GB) and sometimes this makes database unstable and AWS loses communication with the RDS instance so it restarts the database.

We thought this may be linked to existing Oracle bug 30846782 (19C+: Fast/Excessive PGA growth when using DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS) but Oracle & AWS had fixed it in the current 19C version we are using. There are no application level operations that consume this much PGA and the database restart have always happened when the Auto Optimizer Stats Collection Job was running. There are couple of more databases, which are on same version, where same pattern was observed and the database was restarted by AWS. We have disabled the job now on those databases to avoid further occurrence of this issue however we want to run this job as disabling it may cause old  stats being available in the database.

Any pointers on how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of completely abandoning automatic statistics gathering, try find any specific objects that are causing the problem. If only a small number of tables are responsible for a large amount of statistics gathering, you can manually analyze those tables or change their preferences.

First, use the below SQL to see which objects are causing the most statistics gathering. According to the test case in bug 30846782, the problem seems to be only related to the *number* of times DBMS_STATS is called.

```
select *
from dba_optstat_operations
order by start_time desc;
```

In addition, you may be able to find specific SQL statements or sessions that generate a lot of PGA memory with the below query. (However, if the database restarts, it's possible that AWR won't save the recorded values.)

```
select username, event, sql_id, pga_allocated/1024/1024/1024 pga_allocated_gb, gv$active_session_history.*
from gv$active_session_history
join dba_users on gv$active_session_history.user_id = dba_users.user_id
where pga_allocated/1024/1024/1024 >= 1
order by sample_time desc;
```

If the problem is only related to a small number of tables with a large number of partitions, you can manually gather the stats on just that table in a separate session. Once the stats are gathered, the table won't be analyzed again until about 10% of the data is changed.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'PGA_STATS_TEST');
end;
/
```

It's not uncommon for a database to spend a long time gathering statistics, but it is uncommon for a database to constantly analyze thousands of objects. Running into this bug implies there is something unusual about your database - are you constantly dropping and creating objects, or do you have a large number of objects that have 10% of their data modified every day? You may need to add a manual gather step to a few of your processes.

Turning off the automatic statistics job entirely will eventually cause many performance problems. Even if you can't add manual gathering steps, you may still want to keep the job enabled. For example, if tables are being analyzed too frequently, you may want to increase the table preference for the "STALE_PERCENT" threshold from 10% to 20%:

```
begin
    dbms_stats.set_table_prefs
    (
        ownname => user,
        tabname => 'PGA_STATS_TEST',
        pname   => 'STALE_PERCENT',
        pvalue  => '20'
    );
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue in my AWS RDS Oracle 18c and 19c instances, even though I am not in the same patch level as you.

In my case,  I applied this workaround and it worked.

```
SQL> alter system set "_fix_control"='20424684:OFF' scope=both;
```

However, before applying this change, I strongly suggest that you test it on your non production environments, and if you can, try to consult with Oracle Support. Dealing with hidden parameters might lead to unexpected side effects, so apply it at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I have seen this workaround mentioned in some of the blogs but I am not quite sure if it will not have any adverse impact on the system. We will need confirmation from a trusted channel (mostly oracle support) to apply this workaround else our customer will not allow us to apply this on the production systems.

Comment: @AkshayChittoria, under my experience using "_fix_control" is ok in most of the cases. That is why you should try to test it on a non production database. I did it myself and I have no issues, then it was applied on PRO and everything worked ok.

Comment: @AkshayChittoria , as a second option, you can disable auto gather stats, and then calculate by yourself. that should work too. It is actually quite strange, because I have Oracle 19c as well in AWS ( IaaS ) and there I have no issues.

Comment: Thank you again for your inputs. We have disabled the job for now and will try to collect the stats manually. I agree, this issue is pretty strange and unfortunately it is affecting multiple prod databases and this started happening after a minor update was done 4-5 months back that might have upgraded version to 19.3 or .4 and that is why we suspected that the issue is related to bug 30846782.